# Producing Generic or Portable TEX Source Codes Using - the World Wide Web- Standards

Tags: tex-core, web, portability

Is it possible to write or produce a(n) -ultimate- standard coding pattern for TEX source codes those might work well enough across the "World Wide Web" on almost every each of platforms available, maybe from "workstations", to "mobiles" without ever even compiling...?
THANK YOU so much for reading this...

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking here. Please elaborate on what is required that is not already available.

Comment: Yes, and it's called HTML.

Comment: More importantly, it is spelled standard.

Comment: Patrick and Psirus: Come on guys, that's pretty hostile for a response to a 1-pointer. While I know we need to be strict here, we can try to soften our adverse or unnecessary comments a bit, I think.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to write TeX code and have it automatically rendered on the reader's computer, then there is no such thing. Use Patrick's suggestion. However, you can produce PDF documents with TeX, and PDF can be viewed on almost any device.

Comment: :D Oh, boy... :D What's wrong with you guys, YES, I did a typo and I've just corrected it already... :) And, yes, I might not a native philologist for You... :D Do not to try overkill, PLEASE... :D Why don't you just think about others, too, well, I mean, at least " a bit" for a while... :D OK, That's already enough I guess and, THANK YOU All for participating on these posts... :)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough your comment received some upvotes, so I guess I was really too harsh / hostile. I should have written a longer answer, but Marco was now faster. I won't delete my comment for the sake of reference, I just apologize.

Comment: Well, "yeah", I've always been respected been a good example for humankind so, let's leave it already, OK... :) THANK you...

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: No harm done at all -- I know how easy it is to react a bit quickly. Kerim -- welcome from all of us.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: Thank you, sir, SAME HERE. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Patrick pointed out, HTML is what you are looking for, it provides the features you need:

- Standard coding pattern (if I interpret that correctly)
- Works well on the WWW
- Works on almost all available platforms
- No need to recompile

TeX was never designed for producing content for on screen reading, it was designed to generate pages to print books. PDF doesn't have the concept of reflowing the content, the content is meant to be static.

I am not sure why you ask this question. What do you miss in HTML? The ability to produce high quality formulas? Then you should have a look into MathML. However, I have no idea of how well supported it is. Another option is to use JavaScript to render the math (e.g. [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/)).

If you prefer TeX as input, you can try to play with ConTeXts XML export ([ConTeXt ePub wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub)) which can be converted into HTML. TeX4ht would be another solution compatible with LaTeX, though I have no experience of how well it works.

Comment: Thank You, Sir, You already done very good answering and helping us all... :) Thank you, again.